# Why am I getting variable not initialized error?

Tags: java, string, replace, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get all the characters from a string to a 2D character array. The details are given below:

*My code:*

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("Hello World");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,l=0;       //as you can see, n is initialized
        String x="";
        char[][] arr1=new char[10][10];
        if(sc.hasNextInt())
            n=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(sc.hasNextLine())
                x=sc.nextLine();
            //char[] arr=x.toCharArray();
            if(x.length()==n){
                   for(int j=l;j<arr1.length;j++){
                       for(int k=0;k<arr1.length;k++){
                           arr1[j][k]=x.charAt(i);
                       }
                       x="";
                       ++l;
                       break;
                   }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(arr1);
    }
}
```

*Error:*

```
error: variable n might not have been initialized
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
```

What's this? Variable n is already initialized. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your input loop is broken for a start.  It reads two lines, and then the next time around the loop, overwrites the second of those lines.

Comment: @User-Upvotedon'tsayThanks huh... true. My comment(s) will self-destruct shortly.

Answer (score 4):

You can only replace a `char` with a `char` or a `CharSequence` with a `CharSequence` (as those are the only overloads defined for `String#replace`), not a `char` with a `String`. Converting the first argument to a `String` (which is a `CharSequence`) with `String.valueOf` will solve the issue.

```
ar[j] = ar[j].replace(String.valueOf(ar[i].charAt(k)), "");
```

Comment: I followed your solution, but now I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at Main.main(Main.java:10)`

Comment: @Abhishek What is the input that is causing this problem?

Comment: @Abhishek Isn't line 10 `N=sc.nextInt();`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use Java 8 stream API, method `simplify` may be presented as follows:

- using Stream `reduce` operation to join strings in the input array
- using String `replaceAll` method with a regexp replacing all previously detected characters with empty literal:

```
public static String simplify(String... arr) {
        
    return Arrays
            .stream(arr)
            .reduce("", // empty accumulator
                (s1, s2) -> s1 + (s1.isEmpty() ? s2 : s2.replaceAll("[" + s1 + "]", ""))
            );
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(simplify("abcdef", "fghij"));
System.out.println(simplify("abcdef", "fghij", " jklmn"));
```

**Output**

[Online demo](https://onlinegdb.com/HkBvijrfv)

```
abcdefghij
abcdefghij klmn
```